# RSS not well formatted (encoding?)

Tags: xml, encoding, rss

Why if I show this link in chrome (http://www.gamempire.it/rss) and this (http://www.cosedicucina.it/feed), the second one is well recognized as xml by chrome, and the first not?

Is it an encoding problem or something that I miss in the first link?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first is served with an RSS content type. The second with a generic XML content type.

Chrome doesn't support RSS.